# Knex update: using an aggregate function like max

Tags: knex.js

I am using Bookshelf and I am new to Knex.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For table foo, I would like to update the row identified by the variable ?`myId` in the table foo setting the column bar to be the max(bar) + 1.

Also, I need this to run synchronously as the next steps are dependent upon this.  Its basically looking like an auto-increment column, but its not being used for this purpose.

```
UPDATE foo,
       (SELECT MAX(bar) AS max_bar FROM foo) AS x 
SET foo.bar = x.max_bar + 1
WHERE foo.id = ?myId
```